# HAProxy number of possible forwarding/dispatching rules?

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

We are going to uppgrade our web application (A1) to a new plattform (A2). Content will be moved piece by piece and from a user perspective you wont know if you are visiting pages that resides in A1 or A2. To achieve this we have to dispatch visitor to A1 or A2 based on urlpattern and we have been looking to use  HAproxy for this but.... Lets say we have about 20000-50000 pages is this even possible to set so many forwarding/dispatching-rules based on url-patterns in HAproxy? Some of them we can use regular expression but a lot of them we must specify exact url-pattern.

Is this possible using HAproxy and still having good performance?
If no I would be glad if someone could point me in right direction how I can solve this in a good way

Thanks!